# SSRS Page Break

Tags: reporting-services

The page break is happening exactly as it should and I know this because exporting it to excel it does create a new tab at the page break location. I also see it in the preview window of SSRS. However, exporting to anything else or printing directly it does not page break.

any hints?

I should be clear this is all within one Tablix(List) grouped.

I know such grouping and page breaking can get messed up and more information would usually be needed however I think the fact that its working exactly as I expect in Excel but not in any other method is very strange

Answer (score 0):

My Rectangle had expanded to a size larger then my page break one once I put in a sub report and I did not notice the size had change.

Thus one rectangle was overlapping the other